# .Jar is not opening

Tags: java, jar

I'm having trouble opening a jar filewith java. I've tried uninstalling java and reinstalling it(and different types of java, JDK) and have tried opening the file with .java, .javaw, and .javaws in both the jre and jdk files in the java folder. When I use the .java it opens a black command console for a split second and then closes. I'm running windows 8. I have ran the same file on other pc, my pc doesn't want to open the .jar file. I am using intellij idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jar is an ordinary zip file...

Comment: Open console, go to the folder with your file write `java -jar FILE_NAME` see what it tells you.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error running the jar file. It displays for a split second and the it exists.

Try running it from the command line. That will give you more insight in to the  error that prevents you from running the jar file.

Go to cmd (press Windows key and type 'cmd', press Enter). Navigate to the directory where you have the jar file and execute

> java -jar yourJarName.jar

Substitute 'yourJarName' with the name of your jar file. Now you should be able to see the error, and we can work on it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it from console

```
    > java -jar your_jar_file.jar
```

To see what could it be wrong?

Comment: How is this different from the other answer and comments?

Comment: Why the downvote? haven't you ever begun an answer and posted it only to later see that someone else answered it a few seconds before? This answer is probably the same because when Gin Sheng was typing the answer, the previous answer had not yet been posted - they are only 2 minutes apart

Comment: I don't get it either. I think my answer isn't as complete as the one Martin gave, perhaps.